# Using @use for importing media queries file SASS

Tags: css, import, sass, media-queries, load-order

When importing my .scss media queries file into my main.scss I would like the media queries to be loaded in after my initial styles to avoid errors.

The problem is that @use rules must be written before any other rules. I can include it for now by using @import at the end of the main.scss file but as @import is being deprecated, I'd like to know if there is a method of utilising @use without creating any more files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare your media queries as a [`@mixin`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) you can `@include` them wherever you want:

### _media.scss

```
@mixin queries {
  @media (min-width: 300px) {
    .second {
      background: green;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    .third {
      background: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

### style.scss

```
@use "media";

.first {
  background: red;
}

@include media.queries;
```

### style.css

After running `sass style.scss style.css` you'll get:

```
.first {
  background: red;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .second {
    background: green;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .third {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```